# Django Haystack + Solr : To get non redundant results in a query

Tags: solr, full-text-search, django-haystack

This may be a very basic question. But still any links / solution will be helpful.

The indexes looks like this, for model 'Amodel'

```
id        name               user
1      Some name              u1
2      Some name              u2
3      Some name              u3
4      Not some name          u1
5      Not some name          u4
6      name 1                 u5
7      name 2                 u1
8      name 3                 u3
9      name 4                 u1
```

The query to get the values 'name' filed

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Amodel).filter(name = 'name').values_list('name')[0:5]
```

This will of course give the redundant results

```
['Some name', 'Some name', 'Some name', 'Not some name', 'Not some name']
```

But how can I get unique results like this

```
['Some name', 'Not some name', 'name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3']
```

Comment: Is there a distinct keyword? I am not familiar with solr.

Comment: Was looking around for 'distinct' and 'unique' keyword for quite sometime, did not get any solution. But some preferred faceting / grouping, but was not able to fit in those properly here.

Comment: As i see it could be solved by using facets, do you need help with which params to use, to query for facets?

Comment: I have used facets only for the counts, but not sure on how to use it for this particular case. Yes, a working solution will be nice.

Comment: You can do field collapsing on "name" field, and return only 1 result per group. This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/4303516/689625

Comment: @jay: Thanks for the link. I'm using haystack v2.1.0 and there is no support of the 'group' API. [Haystack v2.1.0 searchqueryset api](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/searchqueryset_api.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Solr's perspective, [Field Collapsing](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) is what you need. The bad news is this feature not implemented yet by Django Haystack. There is a [pull-request exists](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/pull/394) but waiting to merge since 3 years.

Anyway, you can try [this experimental backend](https://gist.github.com/acdha/3750774) which written by Chris Adams.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I saw the same kind of answer (to use grouping) in some other thread too. I'll give this a try and update back. But thanks for confirming that the grouping is not yet supported in haystack.

Answer (score 0):

Use set() to get rid of the duplicates.

`set(SearchQuerySet().models(Amodel).filter(name = 'name').values_list('name')[0:5])`

Comment: I'm looking for solution around the solr / haystack features which I may be missing / don't know yet / don't know how to use it yet and not at our application level. With your solution the slicing `[0:5]` looses it's preference, as it is performed in the solr, and my expectation is 5 non redundant result in a single query. The problem with the `set()` is, for the first time result will be `['Some name', 'Not some name']`, and I need to query again to get the subsequent result `['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3']`, which I really like to avoid (redundant / repeated queries).

Comment: What's your template looking like? Do you index both `id` and `user`? If yes, remove them.

Comment: The `id` is just used for reference to show here, it is not being indexed (haystack will internally index the id as `django_id`). I definitely need to index the `user` as some of the filter logic is dependent on it. I've show it here to indicate that the `name` is being added by different users, that is all.