# How to get solr results with atmost one document from each website

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I am using solr 4.10.3. I have crawled some documents from web. Now when I query there appears one thing that I do not want. That is: more than one results are show from one website.

What I want is that atmost one result should be shown from each website in results.

Comment: Would [Field Collapsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302729/solr-how-to-group-by-and-limit) do? This is similar to a Group By in a relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grouping on host or whatever else you have that uniquely identifies a website: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

`group=true&groups.field=host`